# Factory in Service

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I have a factory that i can't edit:

```
factory('UsersForAnimale', ['$q', '$http',function($q, $http) {
var getUsers = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('ServerRest/users-for-animale.php')
        .success(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data); // Successo: risolvo la promise
        })
        .error(function(reason) {
            deferred.reject(reason); // Errore: rigetto la promise
        });

    return deferred.promise; // Restituisco una promise
}

return {
    getUsers: getUsers
};
```

}]);

I created a service because i want to try to manipulate the result:

```
    .service('ContatoreUtentiAndPromise', ['UsersForAnimale',function(UsersForAnimale)
{

    var Numero = 0;

    this.getNumber = function()
    {
        UsersForAnimale.getUsers().then(function(data)
        {
            this.Numero = data.length;
            console.log("Numero="+this.Numero);

            this.Numero = this.Numero+10;

            return this.Numero;

        });



    }

}]);
```

The console show me the correct value but controller show nothing.

```
    .controller('ListaUtentiContaConSapInBoxCtrl', ['ContatoreUtentiAndPromise','$scope','$q', function (ContatoreUtentiAndPromise,$scope,$q)
{

    $scope.numeroUtenti=ContatoreUtentiAndPromise.getNumber();


}]);
```

I wonder where I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the promise from your service method, because the factory method is asynchronous:

```
this.getNumber = function() {
    return UsersForAnimale.getUsers().then(function(data) {
        this.Numero = data.length;
        console.log("Numero="+this.Numero);

        this.Numero = this.Numero+10;

        return this.Numero;
    });
}
```

and then use it this way:

```
ContatoreUtentiAndPromise.getNumber()
.then(function(num) {
    $scope.numeroUtenti = num;
});
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!